# Why automatically generated CMakeLists.txt from CLion doesn't work with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, clion

I need help. I am trying to use the CLion IDE together with the Qt Framework. When I create a project in CLion, it automatically generates to me CMakeLists.txt and main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(untitled4)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(untitled4 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(untitled4
        Qt6::Core
        Qt6::Gui
        Qt6::Widgets
        )
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hello world!", nullptr);
    button.resize(200, 100);
    button.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

When I try to compile a program, the compiler throws an error:

```
/home/xxx/CLionProjects/untitled4/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <QApplication>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I am using Ubuntu 23.04, the Qt6 libraries are in the directory /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6

I'm trying to understand why CLion generates exactly this CMakeLists.txt and why it doesn't work, as well as fix this misunderstanding. Thank you in advance

I used the CMakeLists.txt, generated automatically by Qt Creator in CLion IDE:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(untitled3 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        )

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(untitled3
            MANUAL_FINALIZATION
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
            )
    # Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
    #    set_property(TARGET untitled APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
    #                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
    # For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(untitled3 SHARED
                ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
                )
        # Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
        #    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(untitled3
                ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
                )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(untitled3 PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

set_target_properties(untitled3 PROPERTIES
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
        MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
        WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
        )

install(TARGETS untitled3
        BUNDLE DESTINATION .
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
        )

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(untitled3)
endif()
```

As expected, it worked and the program compiled, however I don't understand why the automatically generated one doesn't work CMakeLists.txt by CLion.

Edit:
[CLion CMake configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQMOw.png)

Thanks again to everyone

Comment: The `CMakeLists.txt` from your CLion works fine on Qt Creator, could you show us you CLion Configuration? The problem might be there, `find package` is not successful, see this [Qt Documentation: Get started with CMake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-get-started.html), and this: [JetBrains Qt projects CMake settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#cmake-settings)